# Stored Procedure in CI

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures

I did

$result = $this->db->query("call {sp_create_bill($sales_id)} ");

But i got

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{sp_create_bill(25)}' at line 1

call {sp_create_bill(25)}

Comment: go to MySQL window thru browser and try executing query yourself, does it work?

Comment: $Kyslik Yes it works, it returns ta required answer